# geometric irregularities in pde's

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, singularity-theory, asymptotics, micro-local-analysis, growth-rate

The following question is intended for a person more acquainted with the works of Yves Laurent.

see: http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1987_4_20_3_391_0.pdf (French)

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000791329695 (English)

for a review.

Specifically, I understand that in the case of ordinary differential equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(x)y^{(i)}(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
$a_i(x)$ meromorphic, the singular points of $y(x)$ can be categorized as either regular or irregular, and further, the irregular singular points can be labeled according to their Gevrey class.  The works of Ramis and Malgrange showed that a Newton polygon can be constructed from $a_i(x)$ and it's vertices define the jumps in the index of the differential operator over $C[[x]]_s$, the formal power series of Gevrey class $s$.

Going to multidimensions $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, the partial differential operator 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(x,D)=\sum_\alpha^m P_\alpha(x)D^\alpha
\end{eqnarray*}
also defines a Newton polygon, which is related in some way to a pair of filtrations defined by Laurent.  One cannot define an irregularity index but it is possible to define an irregularity sheaf, which in some way encodes the singularity information, though I remain fuzzy on the details.

My question is, for the case of the operator $P(x,D)$ above, how much can Laurent say about its solution space, and its singularities, compared to the one-dimensional case?  I understand that the first thing to go is the formal series $C[[x]]$, which are replaced by microfunctions, but can he give a complete description of the growth of solutions in the same way that Gevrey asymptotics determine how fast a solution diverges near a singular point?  I want to emphasize that this is not the holonomic case, which I realize most of his work is about.  However, in his a review paper he eludes to this case and omits the details, pointing to original sources either behind a pay wall or published in French!  Any help deciphering this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a link to the review paper, and/or the various original sources that you are having difficulty (pay wall or linguistic) accessing?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I've added the two inaccessible one's and here's a link to the review article http://www.emis.de/journals/SC/2004/8/pdf/smf_sem-cong_8_411-430.pdf